# Add a dll assembly to SQL Server using Advanced Installer

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, advanced-installer

I've developed a Windows application using C# and SQL Server 2008 R2. My application needs to use some database algorithms for some optimization and speed, so I created a `.dll` assembly.

Consequently most of the stored procedures using this assembly for their T-SQL resulting.

I know how to add this assembly to SQL Server like this:

First step:

```
/* enable CLR in SQL Server */
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled' , '1' 
go 
reconfigure;
```

Then second step:

```
/* Add ASSEMBLY to SQL Server */
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLFunction
FROM 'FolderPath\...\SQLFunction.dll'
```

Now I want to publish my Windows app using Advanced Installer. The challenge is adding the second step to Advanced Installer SQL query because of the variable path of `'FolderPath\...\SQLFunction.dll'`.

I can add the first step to Advanced Installer SQL query but how can I add that dll from `app directory` using SQL query or other ways.

Please help and write your ideas here because I think this is a common challenge.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

All you should do will be to add your DLL in Files and Folders view from your project and then in SQL Scripts view use the SQL Replacement tab to replace a pattern from your script with the DLL path from Files and Folders view. Here is a [practical example](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-custom-property-in-script.html) on their web site.

Comment: I follow instructions, but [APPDIR] does not get application installation folder and throw me an error on installation.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to install dll directly from dll (content) in hex.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLFunction
FROM 0x0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF000[and much much hex more - no spaces and no newlines]
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

There are plenty of hex editors which, will allow you to download hex of your dll file. There is also plugin for notepad++ (Hex-Editor)

To install it go to Plugins->Plugin manager->Show plugin manager
Find Hex-Editor, check it and hit Install. Probably message saying that plugin manager should be updated. Click "No". Then the hex editor will be installed and notepad++ should be restarted.

After that, open your dll file (with notepad++) You will have new icon:

[image: hex-editor icon]

Click this icon and you will have your file in hex. Copy paste it (and remove spaces) and you are ready.

Comment: do you mean if I fetch hex code of my dll and put it in 0x[here] I can assemble that dll without any physical path?

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I convert my dll to hex code using notepad++?

Comment: I've extended my answer (details about hex-editor install)

Comment: unfortunately, I got an error with your method in SQL server. **The identifier that starts with 'my hex code' is too long. Maximum length is 128.**  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: are there no spaces and no newlines in hex? I've extended solution to what it should look like

Comment: I open my dll using notepa++ then execute hex-editor and select all codes then paste it to empty notepad. finally, remove all spaces between hex codes. Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151510/discussion-between-piotr-and-reza-paidar).